# Varnish 503 errors that won't go away and are random

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, varnish

Varnish is giving 503 errors because it is not able to connect to apache in the back end. This is not constant but when mytop shows wait times in the 40 sec and up range it usually starts happening.

Many times a restart of apache will prevent more 503 errors from continuing. However sometimes a restart of apache and varnish does nothing.
That is when I change ports on Apache and the problem goes away for a few hours, maybe even 12 hours or so. But in the end, the 503 errors always come back to haunt me. This is really strange how changing a port can be ok for a while.

I have played with MaxRequestWorkers in mpm_prefork_module, open file limits in limits.conf, looked at slow queries, slow php files. Nothing in Apache logs. I have only soothed the problem but not eliminated it.

I also have noticed that when there are a lot of sleeping connections (via mytop) I start to get 503 errors. 
I have limited connection time to 45 sec and have a script that checks the number of current connections, how long the sleeping connections are sleeping for and I kill them. 
I aslo sometimes mark apache for a restart and have a perl script that restarts it. After apache is restarted, all is back to normal most of the time.

Any ideas? What can I do? I am lost. It never happend on my old server when I had php5 and Ubuntu 12. Maybe something new in Ubuntu thats doing this. Any help would be great if you could review my data below. I have been working on this for 2 weeks.

500,000 page views per day, each page taking less than 1 sec to load many with images.

Cloudflare -> Varnish -> Apache2
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
varnishd (varnish-4.1.1 revision 66bb824)
php 7.0

free shows:
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       65940984     6506388      785104
CPU(s):                24
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v2 @ 2.60GHz

4 1TB SSD drives in raid and I do not see a lot of I/O or processor waiting on I/O

Load will go up to 11 but normally looks like:5.77, 6.26, 5.82. Load should be ok upto 28 because I have 28 procs. Without varnish and stright to Apache load does spike up to 26 and above

Varnish default.vcl:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8082";
    .connect_timeout = 10s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 10s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 6s;
}
sub vcl_recv {
   if (req.http.host ~ "(admin.example.com|cron.example.com)") {
     return(pass);
   }
}
```

Some Apache settings:

```
Timeout 50
KeepAlive on
MaxKeepAliveRequests 200
KeepAliveTimeout 5

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
        StartServers             95      
        MinSpareServers          400
        MaxSpareServers          750
        MaxRequestWorkers        1400
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
        MaxClients               1550
</IfModule>
```

/etc/security/limits.conf:

```
* soft nofile 400000
* hard nofile 700000
mysql soft nofile 1024000
mysql hard nofile 1024000
```

root@one:/etc/apache2# ps -ylC apache2 | awk '{x += $8;y += 1} END {print "Apache Memory Usage (MB): "x/1024; print "Average Proccess Size (MB): "x/((y-1)*1024)}'

```
Apache Memory Usage (MB): 8746.89
Average Proccess Size (MB): 33.9027
```

Varnishlog showing 503 errors:

```
*   << Request  >> 347834142 
-   Begin          req 347834141 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1482876824.797398 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1482876824.797398 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqStart       108.162.219.141 31651
-   ReqMethod      HEAD
-   ReqURL         /226-213-2711
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: example.com
-   ReqHeader      Connection: Keep-Alive
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   ReqHeader      CF-IPCountry: CA
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 209.171.88.168
-   ReqHeader      CF-RAY: 31801f1a54154716-EWR
-   ReqHeader      Content-Length: 0
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: http
-   ReqHeader      CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"http"}
-   ReqHeader      Referer: http://example.com/22-2711
-   ReqHeader      x-wap-profile: http://wap.samsungmobile.com/uaprof/SGH-I747M.xml
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; en-ca; SGH-I747M-parrot Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-CA, en-US
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf-16, *;q=0.7
-   ReqHeader      Accept: */*
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: __cfduid=d20ebc9c49642d5d5e9a0d76783dd140f1482876662; PHPSESSID=g4k9u49ei5tshlred89ttrib42; _pk_ref.3.082b=%5B%22%22%2C%22%22%2C1482876642%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ca%22%5D; _pk_id.3.082b=ff9636b2577d5b22.1482876642.1.1482876707.1482876642.;
-   ReqHeader      CF-Connecting-IP: 209.171.88.168
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 209.171.88.168
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 209.171.88.168, 108.162.219.141
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_return     pass
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       PASS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 347834143 pass
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1482877011.807866 187.010467 187.010467
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     503
-   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
-   RespHeader     Date: Tue, 27 Dec 2016 22:16:51 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 347834142
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1482877011.807904 187.010506 0.000038
-   Debug          "RES_MODE 0"
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1482877011.807922 187.010524 0.000018
-   ReqAcct        933 0 933 222 0 222
-   End            

ObjHeader      Retry-After: 5
-   Length         286
-   BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
-   End            

*   << Request  >> 351045135 
-   Begin          req 351045134 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1482876998.128500 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1482876998.128500 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqStart       108.162.245.39 20158
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /604-343-7911/
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: www.escortspolice.com
-   ReqHeader      Connection: Keep-Alive
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   ReqHeader      CF-IPCountry: US
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 157.55.39.219
-   ReqHeader      CF-RAY: 31802355e3b50c3b-SEA
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: http
-   ReqHeader      CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"http"}
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: no-cache
-   ReqHeader      Pragma: no-cache
-   ReqHeader      Accept: */*
-   ReqHeader      From: bingbot(at)microsoft.com
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
-   ReqHeader      CF-Connecting-IP: 157.55.39.219
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 157.55.39.219
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 157.55.39.219, 108.162.245.39
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 351045136 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1482877013.130852 15.002352 15.002352
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     503
-   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
-   RespHeader     Date: Tue, 27 Dec 2016 22:16:53 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 351045135
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1482877013.130873 15.002373 0.000021
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 286
-   Debug          "RES_MODE 2"
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1482877013.130894 15.002394 0.000021
-   ReqAcct        449 0 449 243 286 529
-   End
```

varnishtop:

```
  9386.38 VCL_return     deliver
  9327.10 VCL_return     fetch
  4708.72 RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1            
  4692.61 VCL_call       HASH    
  4692.61 VCL_call       RECV
  4692.61 VCL_call       DELIVER 
  4692.61 VCL_return     lookup  
  4692.61 RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
  4692.36 ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1           
  4688.35 RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
  4687.20 ReqMethod      GET
  4670.60 RespHeader     Age: 0                
  4664.45 BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1             
  4664.45 VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
  4659.96 BereqMethod    GET          
  4628.04 ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
  4619.31 BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip 
  4579.22 ReqHeader      Connection: Keep-Alive
  4487.36 ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1               
  4487.35 BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
  4450.94 ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: http       
  4450.94 ReqHeader      CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"http"}
  4440.67 BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: http       
  4440.67 BereqHeader    CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"http"} 
  4339.71 RespHeader     Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
  4321.25 VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE              
  4321.25 ObjHeader      Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
  4321.24 BerespHeader   Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
  4207.14 ReqHeader      CF-IPCountry: US              
  4196.86 BereqHeader    CF-IPCountry: US              
  3860.32 Debug          RES_MODE 2          
  3716.96 RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
  3482.28 Storage        malloc Transient
  3423.33 Fetch_Body     3 length stream 
  3139.05 Begin          sess 0 HTTP/1   
  2947.17 RespStatus     200                 
  2947.17 RespReason     OK 
  2933.81 ObjStatus      200        
  2933.81 ObjReason      OK 
  2933.79 BerespStatus   200             
  2933.79 BerespReason   OK           
  2833.36 ReqHeader      Accept: */*     
  2817.50 BereqHeader    Accept: */*  
  2539.02 VCL_return     hash       
  2492.11 VCL_call       MISS         
  2171.20 VCL_call       PASS                               
  2153.92 VCL_return     pass                
  1559.31 ReqHeader      Pragma: no-cache
  1551.06 BereqHeader    Pragma: no-cache
  1546.19 ReqHeader      Cache-Control: no-cache               
  1539.36 ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bi
  1533.79 BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bi
  1529.78 RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  1527.04 BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  1527.04 ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  1511.80 BerespHeader   Pragma: no-cache                      
  1511.80 ObjHeader      Pragma: no-cache
  1511.80 BerespHeader   Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate              
  1510.32 RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache     
  1509.84 RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Apache Errorlog only shows the following (this is due to LibOffice, not sure where the error is at but I dont think this is effecting anything):

```
W: Unknown node under /registry/extlang: deprecated
W: Unknown node under /registry/grandfathered: comments
W: Unknown node under /registry/extlang: deprecated
W: Unknown node under /registry/grandfathered: comments
W: Unknown node under /registry/grandfathered: comments
```

Mytop showing some sleeping entires. I let them sleep for 45 sec. Before they would sometimes sleep for 900 sec or more and Apache would crash or Varnish would show 503 errors

```
 Key Efficiency: 99.0%  Bps in/out: 51.7k/ 1.1M   Now in/out: 129.5k/593.4k

       Id      User         Host/IP         DB       Time    Cmd    State Query                                                                                                                                                                  
       --      ----         -------         --       ----    ---    ----- ----------                                                                                                                                                             
   540558        em       localhost         em         44  Sleep                                                                                                                                                                                 
   540753        em       localhost         em         42  Sleep                                                                                                                                                                                 
   540802        em       localhost         em         36  Sleep                                                                                                                                                                                 
   540849        em       localhost         em         29  Sleep                                                                                                                                                                                 
   540921        em       localhost         em         22  Sleep                                                                                                                                                                                 
   541603        mt       localhost         mt         15  Sleep                                                                                                                                                                                 
   541710        em       localhost         em         14  Sleep                                                                                                                                                                                 
   541598        em       localhost         em         13  Sleep                                                                                                                                                                                 
   541607        em       localhost         em         13  Sleep                                                                                                                                                                                 
   541798        em       localhost         em         13  Sleep
```

Comment: It seems that the problem is somewhere in Apache. Based on this piece of your varnishlog `-    Timestamp      Fetch: 1482877011.807866 187.010467 187.010467` Varnish fails to fetch from it after 187 seconds but II can't find why your apache is taking so long to answer.

Comment: Thats what it looks liek too. No error logs with apache, I have tried several changes to settings in Apache, turned of persistent connections for php mysql. When I restart Apache, show process list sleeping process go away. But it always comes back. How to track this prob down?

Comment: I still have this problem and it won't go away. I have to change the apache port it's listening on every day. As soon as i do that t is solved for a few hours, sometimes even 2 days. I am stumpped. Maybe someone out there can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you check for the apache worker and closely look the apache server status to see how many requests you are getting,

I think your apache is getting overloaded or

Check your database server, does it functioning properly or is it giving a high CPU  load. sometimes apache get delayed due to overhead in the database

check how many database connection you are getting and does your DB server is handling them .